# How to assign variables properly in this Python code?

Tags: python, argparse

So I created this Network Scanner tool that works well in Kali Linux terminal, the only problem I have is; if you check the end of the code you will find an if statement, I just want to set `scan_result` to `scan(ip_range)` if no arguments were given, otherwise `scan_result` should be set to `scan(options.target)` ... The code below works fine, but I just cannot figure out why the if statement works vice versa. I'm telling it to set `scan_result = scan(ip_range)` if options is empty (arguments not given) `else: scan_result = scan(options.target)`

Thank you in advance..

```
#!usr/bin/env python


import argparse
import itertools
import threading
import time
import sys
import subprocess
import scapy.all as scapy
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
colorama.init(autoreset=True)

subprocess.call("clear")
logo = """..."""

print(f"{Fore.RED}{logo}")
print(f"[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+]-[+] *** Created by: {Fore.RED}Totenkopf\n")

done = False
#here is the animation
def animate():
    for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
        if done:
            break
        sys.stdout.write('\r[+] Scanning the network ' + c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\r')

t = threading.Thread(target=animate)
t.start()
time.sleep(9)

def get_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--target", dest="target", help="target IP / IP range.")
    options = parser.parse_args()

    return options

def scan(ip):

    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    # print(arp_request.summary())
    # scapy.ls(scapy.ARP())
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast/arp_request
    # print(arp_request_broadcast.summary()) #Shows a summary
    # scapy.ls(scapy.Ether()) #lists
    # arp_request_broadcast.show()     #Shows in more details
    answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=7, verbose=False)[0] #Send a packet and receive response, verbose makes the beginning text disappear
    print("\n\nScan completed")
    print(" ")
    clients_list = []
    for element in answered_list:
        client_dict = {"ip": element[1].psrc, "mac": element[1].hwsrc}
        clients_list.append(client_dict)
    return clients_list


def print_result(results_list):
    line = "|"
    print("\n- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -")
    print(f"{Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX}IP\t\t{Fore.WHITE}    |{Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX}   Mac address {Fore.WHITE}        |\n{Fore.WHITE}- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - "
          f"- - - - - -")
    for client in results_list:
        print(f'{Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX}{client["ip"]}\t    {Fore.WHITE}|   {Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX}{client["mac"]}{Fore.WHITE}   |')
    print(f"- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n\n")


ip_range = "192.168.100.1/24"
options = get_arguments()


if options == "":
    scan_result = scan(ip_range)

else:
    scan_result = scan(options.target)


print_result(scan_result)
done = True
```

Comment: parse_args() returns an object not a string, did you try to convert it to a string first?
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-parse-args-method

Comment: do a `print(options)`

Answer (score 2):

Because `options` variable is not empty, it has an args structure. Rather you should check:

```
if not options.target:
    scan_result = scan(ip_range)
else:
    scan_result = scan(options.target)
```